# How to define ENUM in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does SQL Server 2005 have an equivalent to MySql’s ENUM data type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262802/does-sql-server-2005-have-an-equivalent-to-mysqls-enum-data-type)

Is there any way to define ENUM in SQL Server 2005?

I have fixed values which I need to use in procedures and functions.

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262802/does-sql-server-2005-have-an-equivalent-to-mysqls-enum-data-type

Comment: Thanks for the link Ismail. Voted to close.

Comment: Are you talking about how to store set values in stored-procs? can you not use "declare @constName varchar(1000)"

Comment: i check the link but how to use in the multiple procedure and Functions?
I am not satisfy with Answer.
I need something that i can use globally in procedures and Functions like .net.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use one or more scalar UDFs?

One per constant:

- `dbo.CONST_Bicycle` returns 1
- `dbo.CONST_Car` returns 2

One per enum:

- `dbo.CONST_Types('Bicycle')` returns 1
- `dbo.CONST_Types('Car')` returns 2

Or use a table with ID, Name per enum

Use a client side enum to match this (perhaps with validation against the table solution)

There is **no** quick or clean way to do this like there is in .net (as per your comment).

Comment: Means i have to create one Scalar UDF and one Type associated with this. From this way can i use this in Where Condition?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have lookup table named LuVehicle With columns Id and Name.

Values may look like

```
1,Bicycle
2,Car
3,MotorCycle
```

Then you can have foriegn key of Id column wherever you need in your database tables.

To retrieve the exact name of the value, you can have a simple inner join with LuVehicle table. Something like this

```
select empname, vehicleId, LuVehicle.Name from employees, LuVehicle 
where employees.vehicleId = LuVehicle.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server supports user defined data types. You might want to do something with [CREATE TYPE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175007.aspx). But I don't know even if it is possible through User defined datatypes and not aware of its pros and cons. May be someone else will throw more light on it.