# SQL Server stored procedure with C# enum values

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, enums

I am writing some stored procedures for my application. Within the C# code I have lots of enums. As an example:

```
public enum Status
{
    Active = 1
    Inactive = 2
}
```

Now when I write my stored procedures, is there any way of replicating enums in the database? I want to avoid using a table to hold them all, but I was wondering if you can tuck them all away in an object somewhere, and reference this in other stored procedures?

So I want my stored procedures to use the style of:

```
SELECT *
FROM Users
WHERE status = Status.Active
```

Instead of using raw numerical values like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Users
WHERE status = 1
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how this might be achieved?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947353/how-to-define-enum-in-sql-server-2005 check this may be helpful to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the best way to do this is to use a SQL Server Scalar function for the job as follows:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_GetEnumValue]
```

(
    @enumName varchar(512)
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @returnVal INT = 0

```
SELECT @returnVal = (
    CASE
        WHEN @enumName = 'Active' THEN 1
        WHEN @enumName = 'Inactive' THEN 2

        ELSE 0
    END
)

RETURN @returnVal
```

END

Then you can use it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE status = dbo.fn_GetEnumValue('Active');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a set of single row tables, each one representing an enumeration. So for user statuses:

```
CREATE TABLE Enum_Status
(
    Active TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    Inactive TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 2
);
INSERT INTO Enum_Status VALUES( 1 , 2  );
```

Then your SELECT statement would look quite neat (if not as neat as the equivalent in Oracle):

```
SELECT Users.*
   FROM Users, Enum_Status Status
   WHERE status = Status.Active;
```

To keep things tidy I would be tempted to put the enumeration tables in their own schema and grant all users the relevant permissions.

Comment: This is pretty neat.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand, your aim is to ensure that the value passed to the stored procedure is valid.

You could create a Status table as follows

```
CREATE TABLE Status
(
    StatusID int,
    StatusName nvarchar,
)
```

insert the valid data here.

Then, in your query, you could do an INNER JOIN to validate.

```
SELECT *
FROM Users
INNER JOIN Status ON Users.status = Status.StatusID
WHERE StatusID = @StatusID
```