# ENUM for SQL Server without Check Constraint?

Tags: sql-server, types, enums, create-table, check-constraints

I am trying to find an alternative for the ENUM datatype in SQL Server in my MySQL conversion process. I know the check constraint exists, but am looking to simply create new tables for to replace the enum objects altogether. So the gist of the goal:

```
Create Table Enum OrderType {
   Buy = 1;
   Sell = 2;
   Short = 3;
   Cover = 4;
}
```

Where C# could easily call these values as necessary. Any way to do this? Or must I use the check?

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1161357.aspx

Comment: I guess the simplest and best answer for your question is here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262802/does-sql-server-2005-have-an-equivalent-to-mysqls-enum-data-type

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table with these values and reference them in the main table with usage of foreign key constraint. In the code below the FKTypes will prevent anything outside of range of IDs from being inserted.

```
create table Types
(
TypeId int not null primary key,
Value varchar(10) not null
)
go
insert Types(TypeId, Value) values (1, 'Buy'), (2, 'Sell'), (3, 'Short'), (4, 'Cover')
go
create table Main
(
ColData varchar(1000),
ColType int not null,
constraint FK_ColType foreign key references Types(TypeId)
)
go
```

I don't have SSMS at hand so this is not tested against typos, but you can give it a try if you find it useful.

Regards

Piotr