# Binding a DataGridTextColumn or DataGridTemplateColumn to a foreign key

Tags: c#, wpf

I have asked a similar question for `Combobox` and got a nice answer. Now I ant to bind a `DataGridTextColumn` to a `Foreign Key` if possible. Otherwise it would be OK for me to bind a `DataGridTemplateColumn` to the `Foreign Key`.

To demonstrate my problem let's have a look at an example :

Suppose I have two tables:

Cusstomer

```
CustomerID
Name
Gender //ForeignKey
```

Gender

```
GenderID
Value
```

I am using `entity framework` to auto-generate my `Models`.

Now I have tried to bind DataGridTemplateColumn as follows:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Customers, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPatient}" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected"
          IsReadOnly="True" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="FullRow" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Patient Name" Width="25*" />
        <!--<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Gender}" Header="Gender" Width="10*" />-->
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Gender" >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ???}" >
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ???}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid>
```

But I dont know the correct bindings.

Hope Someone helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{Binding Gender.Value}`

for your models

```
public class YourViewModel
{
    public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public Customer SelectedCustomer { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
}

public class Gender
{
    public int GenderID { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

ps. btw normalize table for gender is too much. You may consider using [check possible column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262802/does-sql-server-2005-have-an-equivalent-to-mysqls-enum-data-type)

Comment: Thank you, It was a very easy solution.

Comment: For users who have the same problem in future, please change `Patients` and `SelectedPatients` to `Customers` and `SelectedCustomer`.