# Enums in T-SQL, is it possible?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

All of us know the system function `DATEADD` function (as an example). this function has 3 parameters which the first one is so strange for me. I looked on the Google so much for finding out the parameter type of the first parameter (which is shown `varchar` in Object Explorer window), but found nothing!

I think it's a kind of Enum used in this function because the usage is very similar to Enum usage:

```
Print DATEADD(DAY,1,GETDATE()) -- What's that DAY?
```

My question can be answered if one of this questions be replied:

1. How can I see system functions definition?
2. What's that `DAY` in above statement and how can I write a function like `DATEADD` to accept such parameter?
3. If it's an enum, how can I define an enum in TSQL?

Comment: SQL is a strange language. I believe (though cannot prove) that `day`/`week`/etc are context-sensitive keywords. T-SQL's built-in functions enjoy certain privileges unavailable to UDFs, including syntactical oddities as you're seeing.

Comment: I thing that is a synonym in sql.

Comment: As Dai says, you can't do these things. The rules for the *implementors* of T-SQL are different to the rules for those writing *in* T-SQL.

Comment: Adbout t-sql Enums [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262802/does-sql-server-2005-have-an-equivalent-to-mysqls-enum-data-type)

Answer (score 1):

Day is a type and its values can be:

```
yy, yyyy: year
qq, q: quarter
mm, m: month
dy, y: day of year
dd, d: day
wk, ww: week
dw, w: weekday
hh: hour
mi, n: minute
ss or s: second
ms: millisecond
mcs: microsecond
ns: nanosecond
```

Comment: I downvoted this answer because the interval parameter of `DATEADD` does not have a  "type" - it's a set of keywords baked right into the T-SQL language. As of SQL Server 2019, T-SQL still does not support any kind of user-defined enumerations or named consts.